# how to Use Metafiled in Jquery like using .html({{current_variant.metafields.my_fields.pack_size_m2_}}); but not working

Tags: jquery, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

Hi there i want to know how to embbed Shopify Metafield in Jquery
like in want to do this

```
$(selectors.vareintMeta, this.$container)
.html("{{variant.metafields.my_fields.pack_size_m2_}}");
```

Its Printing {{variant.metafields.my_fields.pack_size_m2_}}

but it should print values in this metafield like 20 or 30 or so on

Comment: Are you using a .liquid file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file needs to be .liquid to be able to use liquid code.

Comment: yes its liquid code

Comment: But is the file .liquid? or just .js?